# Trying to escape period in JavaScript regular expression but failing

Tags: javascript, regex

Our code below is trying to account for periods in regular expressions, but it's not working for some reason. What are we doing wrong? Thanks!

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6EBBJ/).

```
var word = 'g.i.';
var escaped_word = word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
var re = new RegExp( '\\b' + escaped_word + '\\b', 'i' );
alert( 'output: ' + re.test('g.i. jane') );
```

Comment: `.` is not a word character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `\\b` doesn't match at `\.`.

Note that your escaped output is [correct](http://jsfiddle.net/6EBBJ/1/), or if [you remove the `\\b`](http://jsfiddle.net/6EBBJ/2/): .

`\b` matches between `\w` and `\W` and vice versa. `.` and space both are in `\W` and since you don't have any `\w`, it fails to match.

Comment: thanks! what should we do if we need to preserve the word boundary?

Comment: @Crashalot Well, you cannot make `\b` match between `.` and space, but you can maybe use something like a positive lookahead? `(?=\W)` will make sure that there's a non-word character after the last character in your escaped string. If you say what you're trying to do exactly, I may provide a better solution.

Comment: we have a list of phrases, where each phrase may contain 1 or more words. we want to flag words that repeat in one or more phrases. in a sample list of "fire alarm/fire/g.i. joe/g.i. jane" we want to flag "fire" and "g.i.".

Comment: @Crashalot Ah, you might try something like [that](http://regex101.com/r/yZ1pM3) maybe?

Comment: Also I'm not sure what kinds of words exactly you might be checking, but if all the words have to begin with a letter, you could use `[a-z].+` instead of `.+` and use the case insensitive flag: http://regex101.com/r/rP6uM6

Comment: thanks! except this doesn't flag "g.i." if "g.i. joe" is "joe g.i." the words we want to flag may appear anywhere in the phrase, not just the start. should we just add \b to the end as well?

Comment: @Crashalot Can words contain spaces? If not, then it might be simpler to use something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/wU4wG6).

Comment: no spaces in words (but inside of phrases, spaces are allowed between words)

Comment: @Crashalot okay, does the regex I linked to above work for what you're trying to do then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `\\b` from RHS of your regex since there is no word boundary after matching a `literal dot`:

```
var re = new RegExp( '\\b' + escaped_word, 'i' );
alert( 'output: ' + re.test('g.i. jane') ); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

`\b` matches words, `.` is not a word character. Your regex works fine without the word boundaries: http://jsfiddle.net/6EBBJ/3/